# Selectable text in PyGTK cell renderer

Tags: python, treeview, gtk, pygtk

I'm looking for a way to implement `gtk.CellRendererText` to make it support selecting cell contents for copying. [Just like it is done it HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPQpb.png). Another desirable feature is to support Pango markup language. So far I have managed to do render Pango code (far from ideal actually, but though):

```
class CellRendererSelectableText(gtk.CellRendererText):
    # ...omitted...
    def do_render(self, window, widget, background_area, cell_area, expose_area, flags):
        layout = pango.Layout(widget.get_pango_context())
        layout.set_markup(self.get_property('text'))
        # ...
        widget.get_style().paint_layout(window, gtk.STATE_NORMAL, False, cell_area, widget, '', x, y, layout)
```

And here I'm stuck. How do I make rendered text selectable? I tried to get inspiration from `gtk.Label` C sources (since it supports text selection), but got no clear idea of how they do it. The other thing that troubles me is that cell renderer is not a widget (as well as Pango text inside it) and click-like signals should be handled on `gtk.TreeView` level.

I conclude that `gtk.TreeView` is definitely not designed for such a feature, and I'm new to PyGTK and hardly can imagine how to proceed, so asking for advice here. Is it even possible to do from PyGTK?

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to just use the Gtk.CellRendererText and use markup and editable there.
[image: treeview preview]

If you don't want the user to be able to actually change the text, you can connect to the corresponding signal ("edited") and set it back to the old text so the user cannot make any changes.

Comment: I'm afraid, in this case I cannot afford myself to make cells editable, because rows in the table can be changed in some other widget placed outside the 'gtk.TreeView'. This would be a flaw in UI to have cells editable in this case, so this is why I'm looking for a way to go without it.

Comment: The problem is that the rows itselves are selectable. I guess it will be hard to "override" this behaviour.

Comment: yep, that's not a trivial thing. I wonder if it is doable on custom `CellRenderer` level or it will require writing new `TreeView`-like widget with blackjack and new selection policy.